# Creating an ec2 instance using terraform by attaching a security group that already exists

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, devops, aws-security-group

How to add an instance to an existing security group while creating in terraform instead of creating a new security group resource?

**code in var.tf**

```
variable "sg" {
 type =string
 default = "sg-111436g6535hc63xc"
}
```

**code in resource.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
 ami = var.ami
 key_name = var.key
 instance_type = var.itype
 security_groups =  var.sg 
 tags = {
  Name = "HelloWorld"
  } 
}
```

But I'm getting ->

```
│ Error: Incorrect attribute value type
│ 
│   on resource.tf line 5, in resource "aws_instance" "web":
│    5:   security_groups = var.sg
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.sg is a string, known only after apply
│ 
│ Inappropriate value for attribute "security_groups": set of string required.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Try `["${var.sg}"]`.

Comment: Or just `[var.sg]` without the interpolation.

Comment: Both  ["${var.sg}"]  &  [var.sg] worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the `security_groups` argument only expects a list of security group names or IDs. So, it would be better to create a variable block type as `list(string)` as below

```
variable "sg" {
  description = "List of Security Group IDs"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = [ "sg-111436g6535hc63xc" ]
}

resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami              = var.ami
  key_name         = var.key
  instance_type    = var.itype
  security_groups  = var.sg 
  
  tags = {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  } 
}
```

Optionally, you can use the `data` source to get the existing security group IDs by using the `tags` argument.

**Reference link:** https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/security_groups#example-usage

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it is expecting a list parameter, so the code would be;

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
 ami = var.ami
 key_name = var.key
 instance_type = var.itype
 security_groups =  [var.sg] 
 tags = {
  Name = "HelloWorld"
  } 
}
```